# How to transform an entity into composite dto? (Fluent Nhibernate)

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I was exploring Nhibernate and have come across a problem.

I have the following Entities.

[image: Entities]

And the corresponding Dto for them

[image: Dtos]

Now using the following query I am trying transform the Orders into Orderdto

```
select o
  FROM Order o
  join o.OrderItems
  join o.Customer
```

The following transformation is not working probably because of Order being a composite type.

```
var query = session.GetNamedQuery("GetOrderSummaries")
            .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<OrderItemDto>());
```

Any out of box transformation available for such situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) for this, rather than doing it in Nhibernate/Fluent (whether or not it was possible).

Comment: I tried doing that too, but strangely its working when i create a new entity object (eg order = new Order()), but not when i retrieve it using nhibernate. Thought this might be due to the proxies nibernate is using.

Comment: It should work with proxies no problem (as long as the ISession is still open).  What happens when try?